# Not asked for credentials when connecting to Samba share from Windows 10

Tags: windows, samba

I have a Samba shared file on an Ubuntu 18.04 computer. The shared folder is intended to be read-only for guests, and read/write when logged in as (username) and is configured as follows:

```
[Share]
  path = /path/to/folder
  guest ok = yes
  write list = username
```

This appears to work as expected when connecting from a Mac, however when connecting from Windows explorer I am not asked for credentials and the folder is read-only. How can I configure Samba to make Windows ask for credentials instead of accessing the folder as a guest.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/194794/how-to-make-samba-to-ask-password-on-every-access ?

Comment: @Rinzwind I am never asked for authentication, Windows automatically connects as a guest.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Linux and macOS clients that will always offer an opportunity to pass credentials when accessing a share through their file managers Windows will always see your share as guest access only. The usual remedies are:

[1] "map" the share in Windows. That is the closest thing you have in Windows to Connect-to-Server and allows you to pass credentials for "username"

[2] **OR** Force all users to pass credentials:

** Make your share:

```
[Share]
  path = /path/to/folder
  guest ok = no
  read only = yes
  write list = username
```

** Create a Linux user named smbguest, make his samba password simple like "smbguestpw", and have the "read only " clients use that to gain access to the guest share. smbguest can access the share but in read only mode whereas "username" will have write access.

[3] **OR** Create 2 shares to the same location but with different share names. One for guests:

```
[Share]
  path = /path/to/folder
  guest ok = yes
  read only = yes
```

And one for "username":

```
[ShareADM]
  path = /path/to/folder
  valid users = username
  read only = no
```